# Autoincremented foreignkey and added new row in a table where I don't want to

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, model, controller

I have a table named Users with the foreign key "BranchOffice_Id" and a table named BranchOffice with an autoincrementing primary key "Id". I have some issues with adding data into the Users table. Here is my code, written in C# using Entity Framework.

```
currentUser = new User()
{
   Username = username,
   UserType = UserType.User,
   Email = email,
   Name = name,
   BranchOffice = _taskService.GetBranchOfficeById(branchOffice)
};
_db.Users.Add(currentUser);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Until `_db.Users.Add(currentUser);` the value for currentUser.BranchOffice is 1, corresponding with Id #1 of the BranchOffice table. But the issue is the following: on `_db.SaveChanges();` it doesn't save that value, but instead an incremented value (it started from '5', athough in BranchOffice table I have only 4 rows). And last but not least, it added a new row to the BranchOffice table!

Here are my models:

```
public class User : IPrincipal, IIdentity
{
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual BranchOffice BranchOffice { get; set; }
}

public class BranchOffice
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just attach `currentUser.BranchOffice` to `_db`, there's no need to get an instance from `_taskService`.

Comment: BranchOffice = _db.BranchOffices.Find( branchOffice )

Comment: I thought it was the same thing! Thank you both.

Comment: This was most likely a case where your current code and that taskService were not using the same DBContext. To get that original code to work you'd need to attach the branch office to the current context. This can get messy quickly, so a better pattern to look to follow is the Unit of Work pattern which facilitates your data access services across a common DBContext (or DBContexts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an `Entity` to a `DbSet` EF automatically adds all the related entities that are not part of the database.

With your code you can have 3 different cases during

```
BranchOffice = _taskService.GetBranchOfficeById(branchOffice)

_db.SaveChanges();
```

1. If `_taskService` reads the `BranchOffice` from the database using the `_db` context EF will add a new `User` with the specified `BranchOffice`.
2. If `_taskService` reads the `BranchOffice` from the database using a different context EF will throw an exception.
3. If `_taskService` creates a new `BranchOffice` (outside any context and you don't attach `BranchOffice` to the `_db` context), EF will insert the `BranchOffice` in the database, retrieve the `BranchOffice`.`Id` from the database, update the in memory `User`, insert the `User` in the database.

The third is probably your case (you did not have the `BranchOffice` with `Id`=5 but EF created it)

Comment: Yes, the third case was mine. Thank you!